# Using relative positioning with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div with which I display basic user information. The 'search-person' div has a height of 'auto'. This is so that profile pictures can be dynamic in size, up to 170px tall. Now, I would like to have a button displayed over the profile picture, and I thought to add relative positioning to the contents in the div and move it up and under the button, button it doesn't seem to want to work right. What can I do wrong?

here is my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/C9Zj5/

```
#wrap {
    position: relative
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. what do you want to do again?..

Comment: a button displayed over the profile picture, u meant like this? http://jsfiddle.net/C9Zj5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make the `#person-wrap` `position:relative` and then the `#buttons` div `position:absolute`. That should give you the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

div containing relative position should contain within another div having absolute position so that it can float correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you set `position:absolute` to `#buttons` them you will have the button over the profile picture. Use `left` and `top` to positioning the button wherever you want inside `#person-wrap`.

I'm not sure what you mean with *"and I thought to add relative positioning to the contents in the div and move it up and under the button"*, but if you want to show the info inside `#person-wrap` you can use position absolute or negative margin.

**Aside**: Is not a good practice to have `div` elements inside the link tag. Also why you need a button? Maybe you need to rethink the html structure as well ;)